# Call imageView of a fragment in MainActivity

Tags: android

The callBack method `onCreateView()` of fragment class is called just before drawing the view on that fragment, so I created a subclass of  fragment class and I created an `ImageView` variable inside it.

After that i assigned an imageView existing in a layoutFile to this imageView in the method `onCreateView()`.

I have `MainActivity` in which I add this fragment (using xml).

So when I run the application I can see the fragment drawn in the activity, which means that `onCreateView` of the fragment is properly called so the ImageView is not Null.

but when I use this ImageView in the `MainActivity` I get a null pointer exception that is the code where i got exception :

```
fragmentB = new FragmentB();
imageView = fragmentB.imageView;
```

and when I use :

```
fragmentB = (FragmentB) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
```

I got the `ImageView` successfully.

I want you to explain me why it returns a Null pointer when used in constructor ? I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Because your imageView is in the xml and when you find the Fragment by id, you get that Fragment's layout which contains the imageView.

When you use the constructor, you just instantiate the Fragment, but onCreateView which links it to the xml file doesn't get called.

That being said, I don't think this is the **proper way** to reference the imageview.

Comment: so what is the proper way to reference it ?